# Check if graph is Bipartite

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, graph, bipartite

so I need to check if a Graph is Bipartite using Numpy arrays and Python 2

This is the code that I've developed to check the graph:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

class grafo:
    visited = []

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.vertices = []
        self.adjacency = np.zeros((n,n))
        self.visited.append(True)
        self.size = n
        self.color = [-1] * self.size
        self.color.append(0)

    def isBipartita(self):
        finalRes = str()
        init = 0
        self.color[init] = 1
        self.visited.append(init)
        while self.visited: 
            i = self.visited.pop() 
            print("[FIRST CHECK] adyacencia[" + str(i)+"][" + str(i) + "] == 1?")
            if self.adjacency[i][i] == 1:  //HERE IT CORRUPTS AT SOME POINT
                finalRes = "NO"
                print("True")
                return finalRes; 

            for f in range(self.size): 
                print("[SECOND CHECK] adyacencia[" + str(i)+"][" + str(f) + "] == 1 and color[" + str(f) +"] == -1")
                if self.adjacency[i][f] == 1 and self.color[f] == -1:
                    print("True")
                    self.color[f] = 1 - self.color[i] 
                    self.visited.append(f)
                else:
                    print("[THIRD CHECK] adyacencia[" + str(i)+"][" + str(f) + "] == 1 and color[" + str(f) +"] == color[" + str(i) +"]")
                    if self.adjacency[i][f] == 1 and self.color[f] == self.color[i]:
                        print("True")
                        finalRes = "NO"
                        return finalRes

        finalRes = "YES"
        return finalRes

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.adjacency)


#PROGRAM

lenV = raw_input("") #This is the length of the Adjacency array for the graph
lenV = int(lenV)
inputs = []

for i in range(0, lenV):
    inputs.append(raw_input())

print("\n-> Inputs:")
print(inputs)
print("\n-> List with Inputs Values:")
tempVal = list()
for numC in inputs:
    tempVal.append(numC)

print(tempVal)

print("\n-> Split and get into array:")
G = grafo(lenV)
for x in range(0,lenV):
    tempList = list(tempVal[x])
    print(tempList)
    for y in range(0, lenV):
        G.adjacency[x][y] = tempList[y]
print("\n-> Array to check:")       
print(G)
print("\n")
print(G.isBipartita())
```

The problem is in the class "grafo", in the isBipartita method; at some point while checking, the numpy integer array returns a boolean and gives a ValueError as an output.

This are some examples that I've used to test this:

```
TEST CASES
3
011
101
110

4
0101
1010
0101
1010
```

and this is the output that I get:

```
/** LIKE 20 SUCCESSFUL CHECKS LATER **/
[SECOND CHECK] adyacencia[1][3] == 1 and color[3] == -1
[THIRD CHECK] adyacencia[1][3] == 1 and color[3] == color[1]
[FIRST CHECK] adyacencia[True][True] == 1?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bipartitaChecker.py", line 76, in <module>
    print(G.isBipartita())
  File "bipartitaChecker.py", line 23, in isBipartita
    if self.adjacency[i][i] == 1: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

As you can see, before the Traceback call, the last "[FIRST CHECK]" has adyacencia[True][True], and this is not intended to be this way... I have done research on the ValueError, but everything leads me to a point where only in some foreign cases this error is presented, but in my case it shouldn't be causing it...

I don't know what is happening?!

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Unless you're doing this solely for practice, I'd suggest looking into the networkx library. https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html

Comment: This error message means that you are trying to compare an array to a scalar. In this case `self.adjacency[i][i]` is an array and so when you compare `self.adjacency[i][i] == 1` you are getting back an array.